# Python GUI "Property tax" program. When running the program, nothing seems to show up (i.e. no separate window pops up)

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Here's the code I have written. It's supposed to ask the user for the user's home value and return an assessment value and taxes due. 
I'm not sure whether there's an issue with the IDLE on my computer or with my program.

The program is supposed to:
1. ask the user to input their home value
2. give back the assessment value
3. include at least 2 buttons
4. Work (obviously)

```
import tkinter

class PropertyTaxApp:
    def __init__(self):
        # Creates main Window
        self.main_window
        tkinter.mainloop()

        #Creates the four frames
        self.homevalue_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.assessmentvalue_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.propertytaxes_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.button_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        #Create and pack the widgets for the home value
        self.homevalue_label = tkinter.Label(self.homevalue_frame,
                                         text = "Enter your home's value here: ")
        self.homevalue_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.homevalue_frame,
                                         width=10)
        self.homevalue_label.pack(side="left")
        self.homevalue_entry.pack(side="left")

        #Create and pack the widgets for the assessment value
        self.result_label = tkinter.label(self.assessmentvalue_frame,
                                               text="Assessment Value: ")
        self.assessmentvalue_label = tkinter.label(self.assessmentvalue_frame,
                                               textvariable=self.assessmentvalue)
        self.result_label.pack(side="left")
        self.assessmentvalue_label.pack(side="left")

        #Create and pack the widgets for the property taxes
        self.result_label = tkinter.label(self.propertytaxes_frame,
                                               text="Property Taxes: ")
        self.propertytaxes_label = tkinter.label(self.propertytaxes_frame,
                                               textvariable=self.propertytaxes)
        self.result_label.pack(side="left")
        self.assessmentvalue_label.pack(side="left")

        #Create and pack the button widgets
        self.calculate_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame,
                                           text="Calculate",
                                           command=self.calc_info)
        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame,
                                           text="Quit Program",
                                           command=self.main_window.destroy)
        self.calculate_button.pack(side="left")
        self.quit_button.pack(side="left")

        #Pack frames
        self.homevalue_frame.pack()
        self.assessmentvalue_frame.pack()
        self.propertytaxes_frame.pack()
        self.button_frame.pack()

        #Start the main loop
        tkinter.mainloop()

        #the calc_info method is used in the calculate_button widget
        def calc_info(self):
            #set constants
            self.assessmentvaluepct = 0.6
            self.propertytaxespct = 0.0075
            #get home value input by user
            self.homevalue = float(self.homevalue_entry.get())

            #calculate the assessment value and property taxes
            self.calculatedassessmentvalue=(self.assessmentvaluepct*self.homevalue)
            self.calculatedpropertytaxes=(self.propertytaxespct*self.homevalue)

            #update the propertytaxes_label widget
            self.propertytaxes.set(self.calculatedpropertytaxes)

            #update the assessmentvalue_label widget
            self.assessment.set(self.calculatedassessmentvalue)

        #Run the PropertyTaxApp Class
        property_tax_app = PropertyTaxApp()
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Once you call `mainloop()`, the GUI starts up, and you don't get to the rest of the program until you exit the GUI. And you're doing it way up at the top of your method, so the rest of your code never gets to run. You've also got a bunch of other problems in your code (`self.main_window` just references an attribute without doing anything with it, you've defined `calc_info` as a local function nested under `__init__` instead of as a separate method; etc.), and you'll need to fix all of them, but that's the one causing the problem you're asking about.

Comment: Meanwhile, I'd suggest going back and working through basic tutorials on Tkinter and on classes before trying to write something complicated. If you're getting all of the fundamentals wrong, all that other code you worked so hard on is useless.